# Live streaming audio using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, streaming, audio-streaming

We have a need to stream live audio from remote devices and be able to listen to it in a web page.  I can stream stored audio files, but the live stream has me a bit confused, since we will be adding the data at runtime.  Can someone point me in the right direction to show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might consider using SHOUTcast for this.  It's simple to set up and easy to integrate into your page.  (All you need to do is serve up a playlist file.)  http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. If all you want is simple streaming, that is, progressive download, then just define the mime type on the server, and it will stream. Keep in mind that you will have to have an audio format that plays progressively (most, but not all these days, do).
2. If you're looking to take fine control over what's going on, you'll need to embed an audio player and use a media server SDK. Here is the link to Microsoft's product for this: [Windows Media Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  On #1, how would we start and maintain the streaming process?  Would we link (href) to a partial file (such as a wav file), then continue writing data to the file on the server?

Comment: It would all be handled by IIS - it would stream in the same sense and manner that a progressive GIF streams. WAV is not progressive, IIRC.

Comment: In my scenario I need extensive support of audio control over web. I want the user to be able to seek, skip, define loop area and more. I also need it to be browser compatible.